# Copying a worksheet to multiple other sheets - object issues?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a beginner to VBA and I'm trying copy and paste a sheet from 1 workbook to multiple other workbooks. The latter workbooks have basically the same file name (increasing by 1). All the workbooks are currently open

I keep getting an error saying "Object variable or With block variable not set". But I can't see why the way I declared 'names' or 'wb' is wrong.

I've seen a lot of posts online iterate through open workbooks, but I can't do this because I'm copying something from one of the open workbooks.

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()
    Dim i As Integer, s As String
    Dim sh As Workbook, wb As Workbook, names As Worksheet

    Set sh = Workbooks("schools.xlsx")
    Set names = sh.Sheets("name")

    For i = 6 To 15
        If i <= 8 Then
            s = "0" & i & "-0" & (i + 1) & "-_Year_data"
        ElseIf i = 9 Then
            s = "0" & i & "-" & (i + 1) & "-_Year_data"
        Else
            s = i & "-" & (i + 1) & "-_Year_data"
        End If

        Set wb = Workbooks(s & ".csv")
```

The error occurs in the first line here:

```
    names.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)

    Next i
End Sub
```

Any help/links to tutorials that can help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you publish the full CopyWorkbook-Sub?

Comment: I didn't make another sub - I'm trying to use the Worksheet.Copy method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-copy-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

*I've seen a lot of posts online iterate through open workbooks, but I can't do this because I'm copying something from one of the open workbooks.*

You could just add an if

```
For each wb in workbooks
    IF Not wb.name = thisworkbook.name and wb.name <> "schools.xlsx" then
          Workbooks("schools.xlsx").Sheets("name").copy _
              after := wb.sheets(wb.worksheets.count)
     End IF
Next wb
```

around your code to allow you to loop through all open workbooks, except the one hosting the code

EDIT: I've just noticed you're dealing with csv files, so they only have a single sheet anyway.